# Wikidata Sparql Getting properties from a Wikipedia generator list

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I am trying to get the properties that the linked pages from a wikipedia page have.

```
SELECT ?item ?wikipediaTitle ?target WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "links".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:titles "Arduino".
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:prop "pageprops".

    ?wikipediaTitle wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title.

    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
  }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?target.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 1
```

[w.wiki/3Ue](http://w.wiki/3Ue)

However, this query always timeout, even with the LIMIT 1. The problem line is the `?item wdt:P31 ?target.` Any way to fix this?

Also, assuming that it is working. It will generate one line for each P31 found. Is there any way to make all properties fit one single line? Maybe concatenating them and separating with ", "?

Comment: 1. Add `FILTER(bound(?item))` before `?item wdt:P31 ?target`. 2. `GROUP_CONCAT` + something to extract strings you want to concatenate.

Comment: Like this: https://w.wiki/3Vh

Comment: Thank you very much, you are being very helpful! But, why the filter is needed?

Comment: Some bindings for `?item` returned by `SERVICE` are "undefined" (like `UNDEF` in `VALUES`). Then `?item wdt:P31 ?target` behaves like `[] wdt:P31 ?target`, i. e. matches all truthy P31 triples (more than 50 millions).

Comment: There is a small error, you wrote
"BIND (REPLACE(STR(?item_), STR(wd:), "wd:") AS ?target_)"
instead of 
BIND (REPLACE(STR(?target), STR(wd:), "wd:") AS ?target_)
, so the concatenations were happening on the items themselves, not the target.
Here is the fixed version: [w.wiki/3X3](https://w.wiki/3X3)

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: OK. BTW, yoy can post answers to your questions yourself and accept them.